# Is there any tool to quickly create RPC classes for GWT?

Tags: gwt-rpc, devtools

Is there any tool to quickly create RPC classes for GWT that extends RemoteService, the Async version and the RemoteServiceServlet derived class.
The only input should be some functions list and all the wrapper code should be generated.
I hope you got my question.

Answer (score -1):

The Gwt Plugin for eclipse takes care of a lot of the boiler-plate code, including those that you have mentioned.

http://code.google.com/eclipse

Comment: Please check again, you can't specify an interface, and generate code from it. GWT plugin only generates the sample code.